# Token access from module

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

Hi I'm trying to replace a Webform email with a token which works from the tpl file like this:

```
$company_email = token_replace('[node:field-charter-company:field-company-email]', array('node' => $node));
echo $company_email;
```

This works fine but when I try to do it from a module it just outputs "[node:field-charter-company:field-company-email]" instead of the contents of the token.

```
function webform_node_token_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id, $node) {

        if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_126') { 
            $company_email = token_replace('[node:field-charter-company:field-company-email]', array('node' => $node));
            $form['submitted']['company_email']['#value'] = $company_email;
  }
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but kind of lost. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: Hint: Drupal standard is to use 2 space indentation, not tab. It makes it easier to read for us (we are used to it, after all), and it also makes it easier to post code here, as you do not risk mistaking one tab for 8 spaces and leaving some code out of the code block, like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra arguments passed to the initial form function will not be passed to the alter - so the 4th parameter of `$node` in your form alter function isn't available. If you check your logs you'll probably find a related notice.

For any node form (including webform), you should be able to get the node object directly from the form:

```
$node = $form['#node'];
```

Comment: I get the error "undefined variable node" from the module and also "undefined index #node". (I've remove the $node from arguments in my module function.) and $node = $form['#node']; is now in my function.

Comment: You just need to hunt around in the `$form` array to find the relevant object. It might be `$form['#entity']` or something similar

Comment: Just to clarify, this form is on another node from where I'm trying to get the company email. I'm using $node = node_load(arg(1)); in the function now which works. You can see the parent node array [link](http://charters.ibiza-spotlight.com/charter-boats/rinker-sports-bowrider)here the bit I want is [email] => pete@kiwi-designed.com

Comment: I tried this:
$form['submitted']['company_email']['#default_value'] = $node['field_charter_company']['field_company_email']['email'];

Comment: Nodes are _objects_, not arrays...

Comment: So it's my syntax? Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: Yep, you access properties/methods of objects with the `->` operator, e.g. `$node->field_charter_company[...]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12401/discussion-between-peter-and-clive)